# Passing variable from Express server to React front-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, puppeteer

I am new to the MERN stack so forgive me if this is a dumb question. I am making an application which will go to a certain url, grab some text, and paste it to the front end.

So in steps, this is what happens in order.

1. URL is pasted into a input field, which is passed to a React state[Hooks]
2. Submit button is clicked, URL is passed to a express.js endpoint using axios.post
3. The url is obtained in express.js with a app.post method
4. The URL is passed through a puppeteer script which saves the returned text in a variable called "rawTxt"
5. This is where I am confused

I want to pass the variable BACK to react to show on the front end, but I can't seem to get it to work! Can somebody help me understand how to pass this variable back?

Relevant code:

React.js file:

```
  const [searchUrl, setSearchUrl] = useState("");

  const handleSearch = () => {
    axios
      .post(`${API}/jobsearch`, {
        searchUrl: searchUrl,
      })
      .then(() => console.log("Searched"))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
```

Express.js file

```
app.post("/jobsearch", async (req, res) => {
  const string = await scrapeJob(req.body.searchUrl);
  await res.send(string);
  console.log(string);
});

async function scrapeJob(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setUserAgent(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36"
  );
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.screenshot({
    path: "screenshot.png",
  });
  const [el] = await page.$x(
    "/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/h1"
  );
  const txt = await el.getProperty("textContent");
  const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();
  browser.close();

  return rawTxt;
}
```

Comment: I believe `axios.post` will return the response when it resolves.   `.then((response) => console.log(response))`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the data returned by the server in the `.then` method callback of your Axios post request. The resolved value of the promise will be passed as a parameter to your callback function, and you can then save it to your React component state like this:

```
const [searchUrl, setSearchUrl] = useState("");
const [searchRes, setSearchRes] = useState("");

const handleSearch = () => {
  axios
    .post(`${API}/jobsearch`, {
      searchUrl,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      setSearchRes(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.err(err));
};
```

By the way, another trick in the example above is using the ES6 shorthand for object property assignment. If the property name is the same as the name of a declared variable, simply listing the property name will assign the variable to the property:

```
const data = {
    searchUrl 
}

// is the same as:

const data = {
    searchUrl: searchUrl
}
```